# biggest data type in visual basic excel vba string failing

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office365

**Sending a Mail on outlook with excel vba**

I am sending a html with macro of excel but string can't load total of it.Even HTML file is almost 200kb right now i am using, i know it big but nowadays 100kb or 200kb not that much.

Also same time column have limitation of data it can carry and I look for cdo it will not work as it need tobe

https://intaxing.in/mail. But seem string have limitation of send message and failed in half and send half only.

I just attaching some code for reference waste time is mechanism for interval.

```
Public subject As String
Public ToEmailID As String
Public EmailBody As String
Public ToName As String
Public display As String



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer, j As String, timy As Date, head As String, base64 As String


timy = ActiveSheet.Range("m2")
j = ActiveSheet.Range("l2").Text
i = ActiveSheet.Range("n2").Text
j = i + j
EmailBody = ActiveSheet.Range("k2")
subject = ActiveSheet.Range("j2").Text
For i = i To j
        ToEmailID = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Text
        Call SendEmailUsingOutlook(subject, ToEmailID, EmailBody)
        WasteTime (i)
Next i
End Sub


Sub SendEmailUsingOutlook(subject As String, ToEmailID As String, EmailBody As String)
    
    
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ToEmailID
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .HTMLBody = EmailBody
        Debug.Print EmailBody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a limit to the amount of text you can store in a worksheet cell.  You can store the HTML in a text file and read it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, a worksheet cell is limited to 32,767 characters.  So, instead of getting your string from a worksheet cell, get it from the file directly.

First, add the following procedure...

```
Public Function GetDataFromFile(ByVal fullName As String) As String

    Dim data As String
    Dim fileNum As Long
    
    fileNum = FreeFile()
    
    Open fullName For Input As #fileNum
        data = Input(LOF(fileNum), fileNum)
    Close #fileNum
    
    GetDataFromFile = data
    
End Function
```

Then replace...

```
EmailBody = ActiveSheet.Range("k2")
```

with

```
EmailBody  = GetDataFromFile("c:\users\domenic\desktop\sample.html")
```

Change the path and filename accordingly.

Comment: Thanks it help a lot